# How to pass std::experimental::optional of primitive type as function argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I have optionals of primitive types and classes that contain only primitive types. Should I be passing these optionals by reference or by value. I am assuming the optional of a 8 byte primitive adds a bool to align by 16 bytes and should probably be passed by reference.

Comment: There is no blanket answer to this question.  Sometimes you may want to pass by reference or by value.....it just depends on what you need to do

Comment: Sorry to be more specific it's a constant argument and I was looking for which was more efficient.